Cannot create a package version with Flexipage of type EmailTemplatePage
While creating a 2GP package version via the salesforce CLI, I am receiving the following error:
You don't have the right to create Lightning pages of type EmailTemplatePage.
I made sure that my User has permissions granted for managing email templates, but I still receive the same error.
Are Flexipages with a type of EmailTemplatePage able to be packaged? Or is this error simply caused by a permission or other setting that I am missing?

The metadata coverage report does not mention any issues with packaging flexipages for 1GP or 2GP.

After posting yesterday, I realized that Lightning Email Templates are not supported for 2GP packaging. I am getting the error for the flexipages related to our Lightning Email Templates. I think that is likely the reason for the error.

Please provide a self-answer so we can close the question. Ensure you quote the documentation and provide a link to where you read they are not supported for 2GP packaging.

Lightning Email Templates are currently not supported for 2GP packaging, only for 1GP.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pkg2_dev.meta/pkg2_dev/packaging_packageable_components.htm#mdc_email_template_ltng
